# Getting geodatabase to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, fme-form

I am currently attempting to load in 1000 data sets I have in 1000 different tables. I need to do this in Microsoft SQL Server.

My data sources are either in Excel or geodatabases. The plan is to download all the data sources and put them into one location. Once I have done this, I would directly like to set up some workbenches to load the data directly.

My question is what would be the most efficient way to create the SQL Server tables with the Geometry using FME. Then in the future, these tables will need to be continuously updated with the data. As there are so many columns with each data set, is there a quick and easy way to create the 1000 tables without much manual input.

At the moment, I have tried creating the tables individually by writing up SQL Script but is taking a lot of time to create. Are there any past examples I can base this on or transformers that can speed tthis process?

Comment: What is your experience using FME? Because alto totally doable, it might not be entry level stuff.

Comment: There are several different types of geodatabase; please [Edit] the question to specify which type and to specify the exact versions of software.

Comment: My knowledge is just above entry-level, I am just thinking of what would be the best possible way to do this if it saves me time from manually creating the table and the required field names.